# Wso2 Fault Sequence Error Handling Header

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, apache-synapse

I am currently developing an API that will send a request to the Endpoint and will response back to the client.

On my fault sequence, I will log the error code and error message by using the makefault mediator. Everything is working fine about the error code and message logging. It just that, the HTTP header return as 500 (Internal Server Error) for every error.

This is my Fault Sequence look like.

```
<faultSequence>
<makefault description="" version="soap11">
    <code value="soap11Env:VersionMismatch" xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <reason expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
    <role/>
    <detail/>
</makefault>

<log level="custom">
    <property expression="get-property('HTTP_SC')" name="header"/>
</log>

<header name="To" action="remove"/>
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
```

I try to catch the HTTP code inside the message context. The value is null

```
LogMediator header = null
```

But when the response is being send back to the client, it return the HTTP as 500(Interal Server Error)

[image]

Any advice would help here. Kindly assist. Thank you StackOverFlow.

Comment: Not sure, but I guess it might be related to the scope. Can you try <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Status" expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC"/> or get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC') or get-property('transport', 'HTTP_SC') to see if it works

Answer (score 1):

HTTP_SC property belongs to the axis2 scope. So you can log the status code using either

```
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="header"/>
</log>
```

or

```
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC" name="header"/>
</log>
```